# Using docker rootless with new version

Tags: linux, docker, linux-kernel, dockerfile

There is a new rootless capabilities on docker new release,
https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/

We need to run it in our environments and provide **using** `Dockerfile`

I try the following

```
FROM debian:10.6
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install git curl
ENV USER=user
RUN curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/rootless | sh


RUN  PATH=/home/testuser/bin:$PATH
RUN PATH=$PATH:/sbin
RUN DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/1001/docker.sock
RUN docker --help
```

When running it I got error:

```
# Installing stable version 20.10.0
Refusing to install rootless Docker as the root user
The command '/bin/bash -c curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/rootless | sh' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

How can I run it as unprivileged user using docker?

Why? We have some **unique** env where we providing our "tools" using docker (like go, k8s binary etc) but not providing docker itself ( docker cli / daemon etc) to the env.
Now docker support rootless privileges and we want to add the binary and the way to execute the docker command build push.

Comment: Why are you installing a docker daemon in a docker container?

Comment: @RamanSailopal - we are providing our "tools" using docker but not providing docker (cli deamon etc) to the env until now that docker support rootless privileges